# RESTful Best Practices - How to name a report resource

Tags: rest, api, design-patterns

I am creating a RESTful API and following best practices for it and I became in a big doubt with this.

I need to create a report (with charts, and data tables) that it's made of analyze another resources (evaluations), and many other params makes this report to be variable on the data that shows.

So, looking for best practices, I don't know if I need to get all the data, and process it at Javascript, to make the report (client side) so the RESTful pattern is not a problem;

Or how can I name a resource "report" that is made of many other resources. My *non restful mind* wants to create a `/api/rest/reports/executiveReport?evaluation=:id&competences=:id&competences=:id&employee=:id` uri

How can I achieve this in a beautiful RESTful pattern uri? I don't want to process the data at Javascript, as there are many errors, or exceptions that I can't catch. I prefer to deliver the report to be shown.

Thanks!

Comment: I've done something recently where I used the main 'subject' as the resource. I had endpoints like `../stats/projects` and `../stats/tasks`. The parameters differed appropriately. Couldn't you do something similar: `../reports/executives`?

Comment: You can achieve this by having the class path as /report and then specific methods for each type of report like /executive. 

That way your APIs would be flexible for each report type. say executive report take 2 params but some other report takes 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I've implemented a report endpoint called `api/rest/report` and then I have my three reports:

- `api/rest/report/executive`
- `api/rest/report/detailed`
- `api/rest/report/datatable`

and every endpoint has its own filter as params like:

```
api/rest/report/executive?uuid=12345&competences=65424&competences=454124&comparativeGroup=12354&comparativeGroup=98457
```